# Google Sheets data lookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got a spreadsheet that keeps track of fire vehicles I've taken photos of.

I have a master list of the stations(column D), their region(column A), zone(column B) and group (column C) they belong to.
currently this is in (region(A), zone(B), group(C), station(D)) format in another sheet of the same file.

What I want to do is have the spreadsheet to autofill the region, zone, group cells based on the station name. The entry (row) could have multiple entries for the same station

I have had a look but as a real novice, I admit to getting lost in many of the solutions out there.

Comment: You need to give a more specific example so that we can actually show you how to solve the problem better, it sounds like you are asking how to use vlookup or index/match. Basically simplify your problem into one very specific example so that when we solve it you learn how to solve your bigger problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to automatically retrieve the region, zone and group details for a given station.

Use `vLookup` and take advantage of some less well-documented features.

1) return multiple cells

2) return cells to the left of the search value

`=arrayformula(vlookup(D10,{D2:D4,C2:C4,B2:B4,A2:A4},{4,3,2},false))`

In the following example,

- the table of data is shown in the range A2:D4, and
- the name of the station is entered in cell D10,
- the formula is entered in cell A10 and populates cells A10, B10 and C10.

**Return multiple values**
Instead of inserting a single index, the formula uses an array of index numbers `{4,3,2}` to identify which values to return.

**Return cells to the left of the search value**
Instead of declaring a conventional range, the range is declared as an array. so...
`A2:D4` becomes `{D2:D4,C2:C4,B2:B4,A2:A4}`

---

**Screenshot**

[image: Vlookup]

Comment: YES that looks exactly what i would like to achieve. enter text into column d and have cols a-c complete from another sheet.

Comment: What is the value to reference from another sheet?

Comment: here is the link to a copy of the workbook. the sheet "ruralbrigades" is the master list. while the "Rural-Fleet" sheet is the list i'll manually add data into
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRX4j-v5SJoWdROA7NTjjsUXj4owX83PirISbbcLWaGXq07BvYS4qo6zL3td3GxFape2FuImgip4Uq8/pubhtml

Comment: "What is the value to reference from another sheet?" Search Term on Sheet1, Cell G6. Search Table on Sheet2, Range A1:D4.  `=arrayformula(vlookup(D10,{Sheet2!D2:D4,Sheet2!C2:C4,Sheet2!B2:B4,Sheet2!A2:A4},{4,3,2},false))`

Comment: try this. the formula goes in cell A2 of "Rural-Fleet"; the lookup is Brigade name (cell D2 of Rural-Fleet) `=arrayformula(vlookup(D2,{RuralBrigades!D2:D200,RuralBrigades!C2:C200,RuralBrigades!B2:B200,RuralBrigades!A2:A200},{4,3,2},false))`. Note: I made the last row of the data range = 200 because you have a fair bit of data, but you don't have to use the "exact" last row number; you could make it 300, or 400, whatever and it'll just work - which is good if you add Brigades because then you don't have to adjust the formula.

Comment: Many Many Many thanks @Tedinoz. You are awesome. I gave it a go and it works (well of course LOL). I noticed in my fleet list if i already had listed Area/Group data there were errors but easily fixed.
What would be the reason for #N/A Error "Did not find value "XYZ" in Vlookup evaluation?
Looking further into this the cell row is changing for each entry. Is there a way to copy the formula without it changing the row values?

Comment: Did some digging added a $ in front of each row/column reference and it has worked. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @AaronCoghill '#N/A Error "Did not find value "XYZ"' Can you give me an example of the row that generated this. I'm in oz, so at least we are in the same time zone (which is rare).